# Add RSS feed for favourite questions

Tags: feature-request, rss

The "favourite question" system is useful for marking questions that you want to go back to, or what to keep track of changes to.  However, it's not simple to see what's changed - you need to look at the activity feed in your profile.

It would be convenient to have an RSS feed (like there is for nearly everything else) that summarised your favourites.  Obviously this wouldn't be just questions (since you've seen the question when you favourite it), but answers as well.

Answer (score 3):

This [has been requested on the main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions) a long time ago.

Try [George Edison's Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source), e.g. 
[Tony Meyer's favorites on Scifi.SE](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/favorites?body=true)

```
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/SITENAME.stackexchange.com/users/NUMBER/favorites?body=true
```

Comment: This is the problem with feature requests on child metas.  Do I close this as a duplicate (but it's a different site) or close for some other reason, or delete it?

Comment: @TonyMeyer Leave it here. This is a feature request for SE developers, so it's up to them to decide how to handle it.